# Restore dragged movieclips to their original position as they are dragged outside the stage in action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, drag-and-drop

I am creating a drag and drop the game for kids and I realized that when the kid drags a movie clip by mistake outside the stage the movie clip hangs where it is dragged onto and doesn't return back to its original position or it overlaps over other movie clips.

Thanks in advance

the code I am basically using is:

```
     * square_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickUp2);
     square_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropIt2);
     function pickUp2(event: MouseEvent): void {

    square_mc.startDrag(true);
   event.target.parent.addChild(event.target);
   startX = event.currentTarget.x;
   startY = event.currentTarget.y;
}
    function dropIt2(event: MouseEvent): void {
    square_mc.stopDrag();
     var myTargetName:String = "target" + event.target.name;
     var myTarget:DisplayObject = getChildByName(myTargetName);
    if (event.target.dropTarget != null && event.target.dropTarget.parent == 
        myTarget){

    event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickUp2);
    event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropIt2);
    event.target.buttonMode = false;
    event.target.x = myTarget.x;
    event.target.y = myTarget.y
} else {

    event.target.x = startX;
    event.target.y = startY;

    }
 }*
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. As it happens to be, StackOverflow is not a free code delivery service. Please read this carefully: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please include in your question your current relevant code, as well as what you've tried.   This gives people context and a starting point to help you with your problem.

Comment: Formatting your code to the point of readability is also a display of effort and respect to those people who are willing to help. There is a **{ }** button in the editor that indents the selected text with 4 extra spaces so it is formatted as code. The preview area below the editor shows what your post will look like exactly, so it is not difficult of a task, only the matter of effort.

Comment: The **startDrag** method has second argument that allows to limit the area of the dragging. Not exactly what you asked for, yet solves that initial "out of the stage" problem: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html#startDrag()

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to preserve the initial position of the clip somewhere and then use it. 
Basic algorithm I can think of can look as follows: 1 - player starts dragging a clip, init position is saved 2 - player releases the clip.
Two outcomes are possible: (a): the clip is on the right position or (b): it is misplaced. In case (b) you just need to assign initial coordinates back to the clip.

Very simple example:

```
private const initialCoords: Dictionary = new Dictionary();

private function saveInitialCoords(clip: DisplayObject): void {
    initialCoords[clip] = new Point(clip.x, clip.y);
}

private funciton retreiveInitialCoords(clip: DisplayObject): Point {
    return initialCoords[clip]; // it would return null if there is no coords
}
```

UPD: As it was pointed by @kaarto my answer might be irrelevant. If the issue is to keep the dragging movieclip
within some bounds I usually use something like this:

```
private var currentTarget: DisplayObject; // clip we're dragging currently
private var areaBounds: Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight); // you might want to ensure stage is not null.

private function startDrag(e: MouseEvent): void {
  // I'll drop all checks here. Normally you want to ensure that currentTarget is null or return it to initial position otherwise
  currentTarget = e.currentTarget as DisplayObject;
  saveInitialCoords(currentTarget);
  addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, checkAreaBounds);
}

private funciton stopDrag(e: MouseEvent): void {
  // some checks were dropped.
  if (clipIsOnDesiredPlace(currentTarget)) { 
    // do something
  } else {
    const initialCoords: Point = retreiveInitialCoords(currentTarget);
    currentTarget.x = initialCoords.x;
    currentTarget.y = initialCoords.y;
  }
  currentTarget = null;
  removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, checkAreaBounds);
}

private funciton checkAreaBounds(e: MouseEvent): void {
  // you might need to convert your coords localToGlobal depending on your hierarchy
  // this function gets called constantly while mouse is moving. So your clip won't leave areaBounds 
  var newX: Number = e.stageX;
  var newY: Number = e.stageY;

  if (currentTarget) {
    if (newX < areaBounds.x) newX = areaBounds.x;
    if (newY < areaBounds.y) newY = areaBounds.y;
    if (newX + currentTarget.width > areaBounds.x + areaBounds.width) newX = areaBounds.x + areaBounds.width - currentTarget.width;
    if (newY + currentTarget.height > areaBounds.y + areaBounds.heght) newY = areaBounds.y + areaBounds.height - currentTarget.height;


    currentTarget.x = newX;
    currentTarget.y = newY;
  }
} 
... somewhere ... 
// for each clip you're going to interact with:
for each (var c: DisplayObject in myDraggableClips) {
  c.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDrag);
  c.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDrag);
}
```

Another option (if you don't want to limit the area with some bounds) is to use MouseEvent.RELEASE_OUTSIDE event and return a clip to it's initial position once it gets released:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.RELEASE_OUTSIDE, onMouseReleaseOutside);

private function onMouseReleaseOutside(e:MouseEvent):void {
    // return clip to it's position.
}
```

More info you can find in documentation: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#RELEASE_OUTSIDE

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but can I get it straight, how does that piece of coding fit with mine? Where shall I place it?

Comment: It wont fit as you already have that functionality. He must have misunderstood your question.

Comment: @kaarto please elaborate, where did I make a mistake? The question sounds exactly as follows: "Returning dragged movieclips to their original position in action script 3". So here I've posted a very simple solution. To adopt this piece of code is quite easy. However, as it was mentioned before by Organis, SO is not a free code generator. The code posted in the question doesn't make much sense for me as I do not know the context. For example this looks VERY strange: `event.target.parent.addChild(event.target);` It's either a hack or just misunderstanding of as3 views hierarchy.

Comment: "Posted code makes no sense"? It's pretty clear that he already saves original position and returns the MovieClip to that location once dragging stops. And he clearly explains that this issue is related to the situation when you move mouse outside stage.

Comment: @kaarto Than you for answering! I appreciate this. As English is not my native language (nor yours, as I understand) it might be so that I misunderstood the question. But didn't you notice this part of the question: `the movie clip hangs where it is dragged onto and doesn't return back to its original position or it overlaps over other movie clips`? So, it seems to me, that code example in the question doesn't work as intended. And imho, it's not that clear as you're saying. Cheers!

Comment: Hah yeah, a Finn here! You should hear me speaking! :) Yes but he starts it with 'outside the stage', so that makes it pretty clear, as everyone who has used similar stuff must have noticed that issue. But yeah, his question title should be updated as it's very misleading when it's not mentioning 'outside stage'.

Comment: I bet I'll win the pronunciation challenge with my firm `runglsh` ;D ! Indeed. Thank you for participation, I'll update the answer asap.